# Cannot remove Bathroom faucet set screw

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

My two-handle bathroom faucet started leaking, so I am trying to remove the faucet handle and replace the cartridge. When I remove the cap to unscrew the set screw in the faucet handle, I can unscrew it but cannot get it out because it is in a long vertical hole that renders it inaccessible to needle nose pliers. I am sure there is a simple solution here but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried using a magnetised screwdriver?

Answer (score 1):

After you've unscrewed it, just remove the handle and then turn the handle  upside down and the screw will drop out. You could also put some gum or glue on the end of a Q-tip and inset the Q-tip into the hole and pull out the screw. One more option would be to use a vacuum cleaner to suck the screw out. Use a clean bag or put a screen/nylon stocking over the other end of the hose to catch the screw.

Comment: put the cover back on so the screw does not accidentally get airborne if the handle is a little stuck.